# How interpret NOAA Aurora 3 day Forecast?

Tags: auroras

My family is taking road trip in  Quebec Oct 4 to 18, 2019. [I posted our route on Google](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Mont+Tremblant,+Mont-Tremblant,+QC+J8E+0A8/Montr%C3%A9al,+QC/La+Mauricie+national+Park,+Saint-Mathieu-du-Parc,+QC/Quebec+City,+QC/Saguenay,+QC/Mingan,+QC/Gasp%C3%A9,+QC/@48.0658196,-74.7787133,5.73z/data=!4m44!4m43!1m5!1m1!1s0x4ccf82ae867fd6c1:0x8de31f7401bd0cf4!2m2!1d-74.5528513!2d46.2199441!1m5!1m1!1s0x4cc91a541c64b70d:0x654e3138211fefef!2m2!1d-73.567256!2d45.5016889!1m5!1m1!1s0x4cc65d3ab03ba8a3:0x8830c9fe400dcb9b!2m2!1d-72.967707!2d46.6498854!1m5!1m1!1s0x4cb8968a05db8893:0x8fc52d63f0e83a03!2m2!1d-71.2079809!2d46.8138783!1m5!1m1!1s0x4cc02768304203bd:0xfe107b2c38d93d34!2m2!1d-71.0684923!2d48.4280529!1m5!1m1!1s0x4c850d03e6348c83:0x1c9194573345042b!2m2!1d-64.023161!2d50.291457!1m5!1m1!1s0x4c9bbf23b75f9eab:0x4971fdae95f10155!2m2!1d-64.4869017!2d48.8316351!3e0?hl=en).

[image]

Just double checking [how interpret NOAA's Aurora 3 day forecast](https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/products/aurora-3-day-forecast)? It shows aurora borealis any where north to Quebec City on 2019-09-28 1900 to 2200 Quebec time. Right? Quebec time is [UT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Time) minus 5.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what's your question?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape there's a question mark in the title, and two more in the body of the question. It seems clear enough to me!