# How can I see aurora borealis predictions on specific future date more than 3 days?

Tags: auroras

I found just [3 day forecast on NOAA](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/18074/17042).

1. Is there longer forecast?
2. Are there data for past years? Past performance is no guarantee of future results. But seeing area of visible aurora for Oct. 2018, 2017, 2016... assists a little???

Comment: I can't say authoritatively that there isn't a longer forecast - but AIUI the reason for a three day one is that that is the time it takes for a coronal mass ejection to travel from the sun (where it can be detected) to the earth. Any further ahead than that, and it's a matter of trying to guess what the sun is going to do. I'm not an expert in this area, though, so maybe somebody will come along and say I'm wrong :-)

Comment: a CME can reach the earth in 0-3 days so it is not possible to give a longer warning,but it is possible to predict a sunspot is likely to erupt in the near future but magnitude-speed-direction-magnetic polarity is unknown until the eruption occur.